# How can I avoid a cartesian product when joining aggregates from two tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to join aggregates from two tables, but I get a cartesian product. How can I avoid it?

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(c.date, 'YYYY-MM') AS "Year-Month",
   SUM(c.amount) as c_amount,
   SUM(o.amount) as o_amount
FROM c JOIN o ON c.common = o.common AND c.date = o.date
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(c.date, 'YYYY-MM')
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(c.date, 'YYYY-MM');
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre-aggregate:

```
select c.yyyymm, c.c_amount, o.o_amount
from (select to_char(c.date, 'YYYY-MM') as yyyymm,
             sum(c.amount) as c_amount
      from c
      group by to_char(c.date, 'YYYY-MM')
     ) c left join
     (select to_char(c.date, 'YYYY-MM') as yyyymm,
             sum(o.amount) as o_amount
      from c join
           o
           on c.common = o.common
      group by to_char(c.date, 'YYYY-MM')
     ) o
     on c.yyyymm = o.yyyymm;
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you!
What resource would you recommend to learn these techniques?

Comment: @oavaldezi . . . This is rather tricky.  You probably just need practice and experience in working with data.